# Adding white space removal to a regex without using replace method

Tags: regex

I need to extend this regex to remove space characterless. We use ASP.NET validation using asp:RegularExpressionValidator so I can't use `replace` method in between.

Here is my Regex:

> `\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`

Hre the code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbBIEmailAddress" runat="server" CssClass="inpText" MaxLength="50" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqValBIEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbBIEmailAddress" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Checkout">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="regValBIEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbBIEmailAddress" ValidationGroup="Checkout" ValidationExpression="\^w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: I don't see provisions for whitespace, just add begin/end anchors `^$` or do I not understand?

Comment: Yes, it accept white space that is not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that .Net has the concept of variable number of capture buffers.
So for instance, `(asw[^p]+)*` should create a capture buffer 1 object that
stores data as an array.

However, its not clear how it would react in this case: `(?:([-.]\w+)|\s+)*`
Clearly `\s` is not in the scope of a capture buffer, and should not be included in
the group 1 capture buffer object array. In effect stripping whitespace in the
process of capture. But I didn't test this.

I could be reading your question wrong though and for all I know, you are using capt groups for just grouping.

**added**

Your sample might have a typo.
This:
`"\^w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"`
should probably be this:
`"^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"`

Its possible that explains your space problem but probably not.

Comment: This is not my regex. sorry for not being clear. I really don't know what to do. I added some coode

Comment: All I want is doing something to prevent accepting space in email address. It accepts emails with trailing space that is not good

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

> ```
> ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$
> ```